# Which one sounds proper: "They didn't do as I asked." OR "They didn't do what I asked."

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language, conjunctions, as

This is a sentence of a native English teacher, who tells about his experience on how to manage the classroom especially when students are noisy. He says what he did in the beginning of his career:

**When they didn't do as I asked, I shouted at them.**

Normally, in a classroom, the teacher asks students to do something, and somethimes they don't do what the teacher asked. So, the teacher wants to describe this situation.

But, I wonder why he said **"...as I asked"** instead of **"....what I asked".**

**"As"** means **"while"** or **"when",** but none of them sits well here, because **"They did not do while I asked"** means something like "They did not do while the teacher was talking", which don't make sense, because something sounds like missing, *What is it that they didn't do while the teacher was talking*

So, I want to ask whether the teacher should have used **"what"** instead of **"as"** in that sentence?

Comment: It's slightly more formal to use ***as*** rather than ***what*** in such contexts. Also note that *syntactically* they're different, in that ***what** I say* is a noun, but ***as** I say* is adverbial. They both work when used immediately after the verb, as in *You must **do as / what** he says!* But you can't use ***as*** in ***What** he says, you must do!*

Comment: **to do as someone asks** is an idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As** can  also mean **in the way that**.

*Do as I ask/say/tell you* is perfectly standard English, as is *Do as you're told.*